# How to select specific range of data in excel sheets and copy them to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have found this piece of code which works for me, problem is I have more work sheets and I have to run this for each one of them.
Also by this approach I have for each worksheet new workbook, and I would like to have all sheets copied into one book.

```
Sub CopyToNewWorkbook()
     
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("April 2022").Activate
     Set range1 = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C66, G1:G66, H1:H66")
     range1.Copy
     
     
     Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
     Range("A1").PasteSpecial
     
    End Sub
```

I would be very grateful for any help or advice, thank you in forward

Comment: Based on your code you are copying ranges from sheets rather than sheets themselves.

Comment: I know, I want to know how to do it from more sheets at once. I have sheets labeled by months where I have same range of data that I need to copy to a new file. All sheets with the same data ranges in one new file

Answer (score 0):

I have made a sub that copies all sheets in a workbook to a newly created workbook, but I am not sure as to why you would need such a thing. This macro is just a glorified copy of the workbook but with only three columns copied as well as the sheet names. I thought that you could have wanted all of the sheets to be pasted instead of one workbook one sheet in one workbook, but that made less sense than copying the workbook to another. The easiest way I can tell you to do this is to save a copy of the workbook you are working on. Nevertheless, this sub will do the same thing.

```
Sub CopyToNewWorkbook()

'Instantiate variables
Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, range3 As Range
Dim copyShtName As String
Dim newBook As Workbook, oldBook As Workbook
    Set oldBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
Dim newSheet As Worksheet

'Loop through each worksheet in the workbook to be copied
For Each ws In oldBook.Worksheets
    copyShtName = ws.Name
    Set newSheet = newBook.Worksheets(1)
    Set range1 = ws.Range("C1:C66")
    Set range2 = ws.Range("G1:G66")
    Set range3 = ws.Range("H1:H66")
    range1.Copy

    With newSheet
        Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    range2.Copy

    With newSheet
        Range("G1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    range3.Copy

    With newSheet
        Range("H1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    newSheet.Name = copyShtName
    newBook.Worksheets.Add

Next

End Sub
```

If you have any questions about the process let me know. Hope this helps!